# парсинг JSON сайта на java

Tags: java, json, запрос, request, google-chrome-devtools

Необходимо получить джсон, который находится по ссылке https://swap.gg/api/inventory/bot.

Я все делаю через selenium, но здесь это не сработает, потому что с этой ссылки идет перенаправление на главную страницу https://swap.gg. Мне советуют post запрос сделать в java, но в нем ведь необходимо какие-то параметры передавать, я не понимаю зачем это и какие вообще параметры, если мне надо просто забрать оттуда json.

Я делал через get запрос, но возвращается какая-то статистика этого сайта(скрин).

Также есть возможность получить его из вкладки response в devTools хрома, но тоже не понимаю как это автоматизировать через java.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста что можно сделать?

Comment: добавьте полную ссылку на json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уже решено, воспользовался post-запросом